# WSO2 APIM 2.0 Clustering deployment issue when try API console from API store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I deployed 2 keymanager nodes, 2 pub-store nodes, 1 gateway manager node and 2 gateway worker nodes in one server, and deployed nginx for load balance. When i try to access API via API Console, it reported below error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-29 21:10:57,237]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} -  API authentication failure due to Unclassified Authentication Failure {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-29 21:10:57,238] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler} -  API authentication failed with error 900900 {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Error while accessing backend services for API key validation
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.keys.WSAPIKeyDataStore.getAllURITemplates(WSAPIKeyDataStore.java:77)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.getAllURITemplates(APIKeyValidator.java:635)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.doGetAPIInfo(APIKeyValidator.java:487)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.findMatchingVerb(APIKeyValidator.java:459)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.getResourceAuthenticationScheme(APIKeyValidator.java:251)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:119)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:117)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:325)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:90)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:69)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:300)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:319)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:152)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Error while accessing backend services for API key validation
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.keys.APIKeyValidatorClient.getAllURITemplates(APIKeyValidatorClient.java:171)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.keys.WSAPIKeyDataStore.getAllURITemplates(WSAPIKeyDataStore.java:75)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.keys.APIKeyValidatorClient.toTemplates(APIKeyValidatorClient.java:193)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.keys.APIKeyValidatorClient.getAllURITemplates(APIKeyValidatorClient.java:166)
    ... 19 more
```

What's the config issue?[image]

Comment: Are you running with `AdvancedThrottlingEnabled=true` ?

Comment: I'm running with AdvancedThrottlingEnabled=false. I do NOT deploy traffic manager yet at current cluster POC stage.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue, and is [fixed in latest master](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/pull/2880/files). I'll check and update the answer if I can find a workaround.

Comment: After i fixed the code, i encountered another issue:

2016-08-30 04:36:49,465 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-4] ERROR ServerWorker Error processing GET reguest for : /pizzashack/1.0.0/menu. Error detail: null. 
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.ThrottleHandler.doRoleBasedAccessThrottlingWithCEP(ThrottleHandler.java:197)
 ...

Comment: It seems it's due to i configed EnableAdvanceThrottling=false? from APIHandlerServiceComponent.java, if (this.configuration.getThrottleProperties().isEnabled())
        {...
ServiceReferenceHolder.getInstance().setThrottleDataHolder(throttleDataHolder);
...}.  Is advance throttling MUST in APIM 2.0 now?

Comment: It's not a must. I'll check and get back to you regarding the error.

Comment: If you correctly patched the code, and disabled advanced throttling, it should fix this. 
1) How did you apply the patch? Can you try the same in a fresh pack? 
2) Can you move to ThriftClient instead of WSClient?

Comment: I just applied [fixed in latest master](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/pull/2880/files) to APIKeyValidatorClient. for 2)  move to ThriftClient instead of WSClient, how to config ThriftServerHost/ThriftServerPort due to i have cluster of key-managers(2 nodes)?

Comment: Ah, I don't think you can use Thrift option in that case. However, if you patch that properly, it should work with WSClient. How did you apply the change to server? replaced the jar in `plugins` or put the new jar to `patch directory`? You should use the latter approach. You have to create a directory like `patchxxxx` (eg. patch5000) inside `repository/components/patches/` directory and put the jar inside that. Then restart the server.

Comment: I cannot find the source code for that patch. Do you have any build version of it? I have the exact same defect.

Comment: https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/wso2/carbon-apimgt/pull/2880.patch is the patch. You should apply this on v6.0.4 tag of https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt

Comment: Thank you, @praminda for the reply! However, I don't see any v6.0.4 tag (or branch) in that repo. The oldest tag is 6.1.28. Which one should I clone to use that patch with?

Comment: Github UI does not list all tags. It seems there's a limit. But the tag is there. You can check it out.

Comment: @pfernandom as Bhathiya mentioned the tag is there. But github doesn't show all tags. Do a **git fetch origin** and **git checkout v6.0.4** to checkout the tag